# Social Security Format

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to format a field for a social security number so that it must be entered with the correct number of digits and then, ideally, display in the traditional format of xxx-xx-xxxx?

Answer (score 1):

I work for support for Cognito Forms.  We don't have that capability, but it sounds like a good idea.  I'll see if I can get it put on the [Idea Board.](https://trello.com/b/ZS1698De/idea-board)